# regular expression - find and split links in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

another question of me about regular expression, its so complicated for me :S So I'm happy for an additional help.

I have a table and I like to read all links inside this table and split it to groups.

The goal should be

1. Person 1
2. Status of person 1

---

1. Person 2
2. Status of Person 2

So i have to get the values inside the links in this table

```
<a class="darklink" href="testlink">Person 2, - Status of Person 2</a>
```

Is it possible to search just in a table which has a specific

Tag before? like this
`<p>title</p>`(because there are other similar tables at my site)

```
<p>title</p>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="95%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="#999999" colspan="2"><img height="1" border="0" width="1" src="images/dot_transp.gif" alt=" "/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a class="darklink" href="asdfer">Person1, - Status of Person1 </a> </td>
   <td valign="bottom"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="#999999" colspan="2"><img height="1" border="0" width="1" src="images/dot_transp.gif" alt=" "/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a class="darklink" href="aeraseraesr">Person 2, - Status of Person 2</a></td>
   <td valign="bottom"><a href="aeraeraer"> <img hspace="0" height="16" border="0" align="right" width="12" vspace="0" alt=" " src="images/ico_link.gif"/> </a> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="#999999" colspan="2"><img height="1" border="0" width="1" src="images/dot_transp.gif" alt=" "/> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a class="darklink" href="asdfasdf">Person 3. - Status of Person 3</a></td>
   <td valign="bottom"><a href="aerere"> </a> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What language/regular expression implemenation do you use?

Comment: asp.net and c#. implementing is no problem for me but the regex code makes me confuse :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression should be:

```
<a class="darklink" .*?>(.*?). - (.*?)</a>
```

or if you get line breaks inside your `<a>` tag:

```
<a class="darklink" [\s\S]*?>([\s\S]*?). - *([\s\S]*?)</a>
```

So, following code should works:

```
Regex person = new Regex(@"<a class=""darklink"" .*?>(.*?). - (.*?)</a>");
foreach (Match m in person.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine("First group : {0}", m.Groups[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("Second group: {0}", m.Groups[2]);
};
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but this currently doesn't work :(, i don't know why

Comment: according your sample data, note I expect "any character, space, minus, space" between name and status; can you please check provided sample?

Comment: i tested it in expresso :S, could it be anithing with the whitespaces?

Comment: @snarebold: please also check if there are line breaks inside your <a> tag

Comment: please, try also this: <a class="darklink" [\s\S]*?>([\s\S]*?). *- *([\s\S]*?)</a>

Comment: i wrote it in expresso
regex : <a class="darklink" .*?>(.*?). - (.*?)</a>
and as sample text just the link and it works not.

Comment: Yes, it is likely there are line breaks that are not matched by the DOT. @snarebold try adding `(?s)` at the start of your regex. But, what about using an html parser to get all `table`'s and then parse those for `a` tags?

Comment: @snarebold: also tried with expresso and works! please, try to use HTML from your question as sample text

Comment: as sample text i just use now <a class="darklink" href="testlink">Person 2, - Status of Person 2</a>
and still works not

regex is: <a class="darklink" [\s\S]*?>([\s\S]*?). - *([\s\S]?)</a>

Comment: SO removed an important char; please refer to second regex in my edited answer

Comment: my whoe project is a webcrawler with c# and it makes all in background
i have to save up the data in a DB. 
@Bart, how would you easy parse html with c# without regex?

Comment: it also doesn't work with your second link. other expressions work which so  a bug of expresso could not be:)
--> http://img504.imageshack.us/img504/7753/regex.jpg

Comment: I really dont know whats going on; can you please try to run it in your asp.net application, or test that expressions inside 'Rad Software Regular Expression Designer' ?

Comment: uaaaaaaaaa.... it still doesnt work.... damn shit expressions... im tired :(.. really thx you help me .. I have to finish this today :S

Comment: i got it.. there was a f**** checkbox in expresso..
really thanks